# Git - in submodule 'git status' does not give "is up-to-date" info as in root repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-status

I have a git repo with a submodule.
In the root repo, `git status` gives me the status of the branch in compare with remote branch. Eg:

```
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
```

But in the submodule repo, I dont have the second line. 
How can I get this information in all submodules? Thanks.

Comment: My submodule is usually not on a branch, but on a detached HEAD on the commit that the root repo says it should have. Since I'm not on a branch, `git status` can't know what remote branch to compare with.

Comment: Hi Joanis, I am an ordinary git user. Thanks for you comment, should a submodule  be independent? If a submodule does not on its own branch, the root repo will be overcharge by the number of branches? Like a sub repo A with 2 varies, an other sub repo with 3 varies will make a 6 branches root repo?

Comment: Each submodule will have its own branches, independent of the branches in the root repo. When you're working in a submodule and making commits in it, you'll be on a branch where you push your commits. In this case, `git status` will show the local branch and its status with respect to the remote one. However, if you're not working on a submodule but instead got it cloned or updated via `git submodule` commands, then you'll see it in a detached HEAD status. You can say `git checkout <branch>` in the submodule to change that when you need to work in it.

Comment: By the way, instead of `git status`, I like `git log --all --decorate --graph --format=oneline`: that shows me where HEAD is with respect to all the branches.

Comment: But a question: does `git status` inside the branch show `On branch develop` or `HEAD detached at <sha1>`?

Comment: My submodule has it own repo on gitlab.

Comment: Yes, submodules always have their own separate repos, that's how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with Git submodules, the state of your submodules is going to be detached HEAD by default.

When you run `git submodule update`, whether it's the first time or a new commit has been pushed by someone else for the submodules, Git will checkout the sha1 that the root project says that submodule should be at.

E.g.

```
> git submodule update
> cd <submodule>
> git status
HEAD detached at 59fe3c5232
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now, I can see more information by using `git log`:

```
> git log --all --decorate --graph --format=oneline
* 59fe3c5232 (HEAD, origin/master, master) Commit details
* 8762eca8d9 Older commit
...
```

When there are branches, that log will be more interesting: look for `HEAD` to see where you're at.

With my example, if I now do `git checkout master` inside the submodule, I'm still on the commit expected by the root repo, but I'm tracking the master branch inside the submodule too.

```
> git checkout master
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But if I were to checkout a commit that was not what the root repo expected, then the root repo would consider that a change that needs to be committed. (Do `git diff` or `git status` in the root repo to see that.)

If someone else on the team pushes a commit to the submodule, the next time I update the root repo and do `git submodule update`, I'll end up back in detached head mode.

I only bother to checkout a branch in the submodule if I'm actually working on that submodule.